# Add custom property to FOS user, based on username

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

In a *Symfony* 3.4 application, I have a `Entity\User` that extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`. I have some custom properties that are added to the database when a new user is registered, like so:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="string")
     */
    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if(empty($this->foo)) {
            $this->foo = 'bar';
        }
    }
```

…and that works fine. **However**, I also have a property of which the content should automatically be based on the `username`. (A bit like `username_canonical`, but with different logic applied to it. Said logic is out of the scope of this question.) I tried assigning the `username` in a variety of ways:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username_thing", type="string")
     */
    private $username_thing;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if(empty($this->username_thing)) {
            $this->username_thing = $this->username; // Method 1.
            $this->username_thing = $this->getUsername(); // Method 2.
            $this->username_thing = parent::getUsername(); // Method 3.
            $this->setUsernameThing($this->username); // Method 4.
            // etc.
        }
    }
```

…but whatever I do, the property always ends up `NULL` in the database when a new user is registered.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Doctrine does not use `constructor` to instantiate the object so if you don't call `construct ` your field  will always be need

Comment: @GrenierJ, thanks for your reply. Not entirely sure what you mean. I do run `parent::__construct();` before setting the property. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know how you create your entity in your code. But If you do not use `new`, and use doctrine `get`, then doctrine will instantiate the entity without called `constructor` and so your code will not be executed.

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t understand. The constructor appears to be called just fine — other custom properties are populated just fine, and so are the username, email, and password of the parent (`FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`). The core of the problem is that I don’t appear to have access to the properties of the parent, which seems odd to me, as they are `protected` and not `private`.

Comment: I also don't understand how/when you try to create your entity but why don't you use an event listener or a subscriber? You can access the object (in this case the user) in the event listener then you can call your special method which add the other entry or changes the username_thing property of it:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: The entity is created when a new user registers. The entity class does little more than extend `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`, so it mostly uses the default _FOSUserBundle_ mechanisms. I will look into whether event listeners and subscribers are a good fit here. Thanks again.